# Bounding the partial derivatives of $\left(\dfrac{1+ |\xi + \tau|^2}{1 + |\xi|^2}\right)^{s/2}$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, harmonic-analysis

Let $\tau = (\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_n) \in \mathbf{R}^n$, $s\geq 0$, and define the function $f : \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}$ by
$$
f(\xi) = \left(\dfrac{1+ |\xi + \tau|^2}{1 + |\xi|^2}\right)^{s/2}.
$$
A proof I'm reading says that for $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ positive integers
$$
|\partial_{\xi_1}^{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\xi_n}^{\alpha_n}f(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n)| \leq C\dfrac{(1+|\tau|)^s}{(1 + |\xi|)^{\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n}},
$$
where $C$ is a constant depending on $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n,s$.

Just to see where it led, I computed a single partial and the result was already pretty nasty. There must be some clever way of obtaining such a bound, but I have no idea on how to do it. I thought that maybe homogeneity may be used, but I don't know how to rewrite $f$ in order to obtain a homogeneous function (since $f$ itself is not homogeneous). Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: But this is false, right? Take $s = 0$ and no derivatives, then this says that
$$
\Bigl(\frac{1+|\xi+\tau|^2}{1+|\xi|^2}\Bigr)^{1/2} \leq C\frac{1}{1+|\xi|}.
$$
This cannot be uniform in $\tau$...

Comment: If $s = 0$, then $f(\xi) = 1$ for all $\xi$ and with no derivatives $\alpha_1 = \cdots = \alpha_n = 0$ so that the right hand side is also one. It would be the trivial inequality $1 \leq 1$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread that...

Comment: Not a problem! I actually have the solution to this somewhere, but it is not pretty.. I should probably post it some day in case someone wants to know the answer, however, I don't know if I ever will.